# String.replace() and regexp. Will regexp symbols in pattern affect or not?

Tags: java, string

Please correct me if I am wrong.

I want to replace substring in a string in java. And I want to use [String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method.

I do not use regular expressions in `target` substring and I think this method is a good choice.

This method will work properly even there will be special regexp symbols in `target` substring and it will just ignore regexp format and treat target substring as a regular string.

Am I right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you use [`replace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) the arguments will be treated as ordinary strings, not regular expressions.

If you want to replace using an regular expression you need to use [`replaceAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct: `String.replace` does not use regex. It replaces a literal with another literal.